# Unable to update a table due to ERROR 1064 (42000)

Tags: mysql, jira, mysql-error-1064

I did realized that there have been concern raised regrading this error but this one quite different. I have a table below and unable to update it due to ERROR 1064. 
Please help

```
mysql> desc propertystring;
+---------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field         | Type          | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+---------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| ID            | decimal(18,0) | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| propertyvalue | text          | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+---------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
2 rows in set (0.01 sec)

UPDATE propertystring SET propertyvalue = 'x.x.x.x/jira' FROM propertyentry PE WHERE PE.id=propertystring.id and PE.property_key = 'jira.baseurl';
```

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near 'FROM propertyentry PE WHERE
>   PE.id=propertystring.id and PE.property_key = 'jira.' at line 1

Have tried different quotes but cannot update the feild. is it because field type is "text" ?

Comment: UPDATE statements do not have a FROM clause

Comment: @John Conde: they can if it joins other tables.

Comment: @MitchWheat Are you sure? [The docs don't indicate that](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/update.html). **edit** Yes, but that clearly is not the case here.

Comment: Thanks guys for the hint. @John Conde you are right the correct way to do this is as below without FROM clause UPDATE propertystring PS JOIN propertyentry PE ON PE.id=PS.id and PE.property_key = 'jira.baseurl' SET PS.propertyvalue = 'http://x.x.x.x/jira';

Comment: I would just delete the question at this point

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys for the hint. @John Conde you are right the correct way to do this is as below without FROM clause UPDATE propertystring PS JOIN propertyentry PE ON PE.id=PS.id and PE.property_key = 'jira.baseurl' SET PS.propertyvalue = 'x.x.x.x/jira';